# Connect to CRM 2011 on Premise from windows azure worker role

Tags: .net, azure, dynamics-crm-2011, azure-connect

I am trying to connect to CRM 2011 on-premise from windows azure worker role. I was able to connect it to CRM2011 online and it works fine. But when I tried to connect it on-premise from azure worker role then, I am getting error message as "**Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved**": 'http://myorganization/targetdata/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl'

Any ideas?? I would really appreciate if you can provide any thoughts on this. I have been searching on this for past one week.. Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking out your IFD configuration and making sure that everything resolves appropriately there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your Public Certificate and give the Async service Read access?

There is an [MSDN Walkthrough that describes the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328249.aspx).

Comment: Hi.. I see a certificate has been added in Personal as well as Trusted Root Certificates.. But I am not sure whether it has already been given read access. How do I confirm it?? Please help. I dont have much idea regarding this subject as I am really new to this:)

Comment: Adding to Trusted Root sounds like this certificate is not a "valid" Public cert from an Issuing Authority (step 1 in the walkthrough).  I have not done the process myself, so I think your best bet is to go step-by-step through the walkthrough.

Comment: Its for on-premise and for that I have created self signed certificate and added to it. I followed the walkthrough which you have sent..

Comment: I don't think a self signed cert will work with Azure because the Azure cloud needs to "trust" your IFD.  Take a look at all of the Azure Walkthroughs in that section of the MSDN.  [This other walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328524) is a two-way Plugin

Comment: From where will I get the certificate??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter the username as
**administrator@domain.com**
instead of **domain.com\administrator**?